# .nuget Folder in User space

Tags: package, nuget, directory

Due to a problem with my storage, I need to delete or change location of many folder in my User space, but I see a .nuget folder and I would like to know if there is a way in Visual Studio 2016 to change the location of this folder?

It includes all the packages downloaded for my projects and it takes a lot of space.

[image: Location of the .nuget folder]

Comment: See [my other answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53741050/102226)
Override using the NUGET_PACKAGES environment variable

Answer (score 13):

Set the globalPackagesFolder propety in your nuget.config and you can point this to any location on your drive. For an overview of the NuGet.config file check out our documentation [here](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file).

E.g

```
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="..\..\GlobalPackages2" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why the double quotes?

Comment: I think he was trying to escape the quote maybe? I've removed them.

Answer (score 5):

This is NuGet cache and can be cleared easily.
In Visual Studio hover over `NuGet Package Manger` under `Tools` Menu and click on `Package Manager Settings`.

Now click on `Clear All NuGet Cache(s)`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This "Clear All Nuget Cache(s)" will clear all the packages from the default.

You can change the path using NUGET_PACKAGES environment variable

[image]