# Change NuGet package folders used by Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, nuget

There is no more `packages` solution folder in any `csproj` or `project.json`-based .NET Core project.

[NuGet CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-nuget-cache) gets the list of used cache folders:

```
nuget locals all -list
```

Response:

```
http-cache: C:\Users\<foo>\AppData\Local\NuGet\v3-cache
global-packages:  C:\Users\<foo>\.nuget\packages\
temp: C:\Users\<foo>\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch
```

How to change or override these locations?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

UPD 2024: standalone `nuget` commands replaced with `dotnet nuget` CLI. The information provided is relevant for VS2022 and .NET 8.

#### Cache locations

Solution-local packages folders [are no longer used](http://blog.nuget.org/20170316/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild.html) by .NET Core and Visual Studio. The command to list user-specific folders is:

```
 dotnet nuget locals all --list
```

And its typical output (I've replaced absolute paths with variables and prettified it):

```
global-packages:    %USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages

http-cache:         %$LOCAL_APPDATA%\NuGet\v3-cache
temp:               %$LOCAL_APPDATA%\Temp\NuGetScratch
plugins-cache:      %$LOCAL_APPDATA%\NuGet\plugins-cache
```

Notice that the machine-wide folder isn't listed there. However, it is defined at Visual Studio settings: Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources. By default it is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
```

In Package Sources, you can add/remove as many cache locations as you want.

#### Configuration files

`NuGet.config` files [are located here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior):

- User-specific:  `%APPDATA%\NuGet\`
- Machine-wide: `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\NuGet\Config\`

Any `NuGet.config` settings can be overriden at many levels (project,  solution, user, machine). Read more about `NuGet.config` hierarchical priority ordering here: [How settings are applied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#how-settings-are-applied).

For example, `globalPackagesFolder` parameter changes a package cache location:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <clear />
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="c:\packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 13):

From the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders):

**global‑packages**

- Windows: %userprofile%\.nuget\packages
- Mac/Linux: ~/.nuget/packages

Override using the **NUGET_PACKAGES** environment variable, the globalPackagesFolder or repositoryPath configuration settings (when using PackageReference and packages.config, respectively), or the RestorePackagesPath MSBuild property (MSBuild only). *The environment variable takes precedence over the configuration setting.*

Comment: You have a formatting error inside your Windows route.

Comment: Tnx, fixed it, needed a double backslash

Comment: NUGET_PACKAGES worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Copying the .nuget folder (c:\users{username}.nuget) from the development pc which has an internet connection and the updated packages, to the pc which doesn't have the internet connection also worked for me.