# Nuget packages folder issue with ASP.Net Core Web App (.Net Framework)

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, .net-core

I have a Asp.Net Core Web App(.Net Framework).I am using VS 2015.

**global.json**

```
{  
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  }
}
```

**Problem**
By default, all the nuget packages are referring to the default location `C:\Users\XXX\.nuget\packages`.

It builds fine though I want to change this folder location to "C:\packages". This is what I have tried so far.

1. adding 
   **"packages" : "C:\packages"** 
   in global.json.  -- did not work. rather build fails and packages are not resolved.
2. Adding nuget.config and setting the repository path.

   .\packages

     -- It did not work. packages are being restored in the default location only.

Comment: why you still use the preview version? .NET Core SDK 1.0.4 already has been released and we even have now `.NET Core 2.0 Preview 2`...

Comment: and look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541859/change-nuget-package-folders-used-by-visual-studio-2017 as looks like it contains the answer to  your question as well

Comment: VS 2015 by default adds preview version for core. I am trying the above link options and will update.

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variable NUGET_PACKAGES

```
$env:NUGET_PACKAGES='c:\packages'
```

To make this work with VS, you will need to set in system settings or in your user profile. This will require restarting VS and you may need to logout/login for it to take effect.