# Downloading reference-only NuGet packages using the dotnet CLI on macOS, in a Mono / .NET Framework 4.7.2 project

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package, .net-framework-version

I'm a beginner to C#, working on macOS at the CLI. (I do not have access to IDEs for everyday development; I can use one occasionally for a one-off command, but that's it.)

I'm attempting to add the [`Krafs.Rimworld.Ref`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Krafs.Rimworld.Ref) package from NuGet to my project; this provides, amongst other things, a namespace `Verse`.

This project has to be a .NET Framework 4.7.2 project (this, too, I have no control over); thus, I've installed Mono, since I develop on macOS.

My `.csproj` ([complete](https://gist.github.com/ELLIOTTCABLE/19e60ec002f20d636bd2826bb79dfe8a)) has the following in it:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Krafs.Rimworld.Ref">
  <Version>1.3.3087</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

When I navigated to the folder of the solution containing that `.csproj` and run `dotnet restore`, it didn't print any useful information; only the following:

```
❯ HelloCSharp main* dotnet restore
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
```

The instructions for compiling that I'm following offer the following advice on how to build:

```sh
FrameworkPathOverride="$(dirname $(which mono))/../lib/mono/4.7.2-api/" \
  dotnet build Source/HelloCSharpLibrary/HelloCSharpLibrary.csproj /property:Configuration=Release
```

Unfortunately, it's still complaining about the `Verse` namespace from that ref-only NuGet package missing:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.0+0538acc04 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
/Users/ec/Sync/Code/HelloCSharp/Source/HelloCSharpLibrary/Helloicate.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Verse' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/ec/Sync/Code/HelloCSharp/Source/HelloCSharpLibrary/HelloCSharpLibrary.csproj]
/Users/ec/Sync/Code/HelloCSharp/Source/HelloCSharpLibrary/Helloicate.cs(7,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'StaticConstructorOnStartupAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/ec/Sync/Code/HelloCSharp/Source/HelloCSharpLibrary/HelloCSharpLibrary.csproj]
/Users/ec/Sync/Code/HelloCSharp/Source/HelloCSharpLibrary/Helloicate.cs(7,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'StaticConstructorOnStartup' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/ec/Sync/Code/HelloCSharp/Source/HelloCSharpLibrary/HelloCSharpLibrary.csproj]

Build FAILED.
```

Checking `~/.nuget/packages`, there is indeed a `krafs.rimworld.ref/1.3.3087/ref/net472/Assembly-CSharp.dll` downloaded. ILSpy shows it contains the required `Verse` namespace and refs. I just can't figure out why the above `dotnet build` command can't find those refs, despite the `PackageReference` in the `.csproj`.

(All of this works fine when done through the GUI on Windows, because of course it does. The issues I'm having are only on macOS / Mono / at the CLI.)

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43541864/1901309) might be of help

Comment: You can't build a .NET 4.x project on a Mac, that's Windows only.

Comment: That's what the Mono is for, @DavidG — I'm having no problems building 4.7.2 projects *except* regarding the package-reference issue described above.

Comment: You shouldn't use `FrameworkPathOverride` now, as Microsoft proposed a much better option, https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/tree/master/releases/reference-assemblies BTW, what version of .NET Core SDK are you using? `dotnet --info` should tell that.

Answer (score 0):

So, it's not a solution that I *like*, because it doesn't explain why the error is occuring — but I was able to bypass this issue, at least for the moment, by using the version of `msbuild` that ships with Mono:

```sh
msbuild HelloCSharpSolution.sln -restore -p:Configuration=Release
```

(This concerns me, as it means I'm stepping outside the sanctioned `dotnet` tooling; and losing any other behaviour that `dotnet build` may include that `msbuild` does not … so I'm leaving this question open in the hopes that someone can come up with a better explanation.)